# Stop timer in asp.net c# after predefined time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to stop the timer after a predefined time. I am making an online examination application where student will not be able to continue with examination after predefined time. I have implemented the timer, it is working well but I want that timer should automatically get stopped after say 1 hr 20 mins. So my question is that how to write that condition and where? I am using ASP.net C#. My sample code is :

```
static DateTime dt;
int m_StartTime = Environment.TickCount;
long m_Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0).Ticks;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = dt.AddSeconds(10);
    Label1.Text = dt.ToString("H:mm:ss");
    if (Environment.TickCount - m_StartTime > m_Interval)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled=false;            
    }  


}
protected void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: a suggestion for your health while writing code: use meanningful names like startButton, scoreLabel and testEndTimer etc...
instead of Button1, Button2, ... Button 53.

Comment: I am a bit confused - why don't you use a **clientSide script** to disable controls. on the **server store starttime in DB** on every postback check on server if time has expired?

Comment: Mr Franz, can you please help me out by giving a sample. Actually nothing is working for me. consider me as a newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just store the number of ticks when you start the timer `Environment.TickCount` and then in the `Timer1_Tick` event you check if the current number ticks - stored number of ticks is greater than your interval. Then you stop the timer. You can get a value to compare to like that: `new TimeSpan(1, 20, 0).Ticks`

```
...
Timer1.Enabled = true;
m_StartTime = Environment.TickCount
m_Interval = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 0).Ticks;
...

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = dt.AddSeconds(1);
    Label1.Text = dt.ToString("H:mm:ss");    
    if (Environment.TickCount - m_StartTime > m_Interval)
    {
        Timer1.Stop();   
    }
}
```

You can of course make a constant and not a variable and so on, this is just an example to illustrate the idea.

P.S. by the way it seems you need just a boolean startstop instead of a string.

Comment: well, string stop is just for testing purpose, can you please elaborate you answer, I mean can you embed few lines of that code with my code, I am not able to make that. Thanks.

Comment: even though in today computing the panelty of an if statment every 1 second is nothing, i still think a second timer is useful :) even just to remove the clutter

Comment: still problem persists, the counter keeps on moving. I have tested for 1 min. I have implemented it. please check.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net it isnt that easy to use timers i suggest you should read this 
[msdn-article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
For general i would recommend you to use a second timer for that purpose instead for adding extra logic to the first one. Also you should use an enum or bool for startstop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            Timer1.Interval = 1000;
            Timer2.Enabled = false;
            Timer2.Interval = 1000 * 60 * MIN_PER_TEST; // set interval for a test, if it is changing, do this in Button1_click [startstop=="stop"] before setting Enabled = true
            startstop = "Stop";
        }
    }

    // end of the test came, do what you need to do in order to kill the student mood further more :)
    protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1_Click(sender, e); // simulate clicking STOP, though might want to replace that!
    }

    // Added start and stop for the test duration timer.
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (startstop == "Stop")
        {
            startstop = "Start";
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
            Timer2.Enabled = true;
            Button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
        else
        {
            startstop = "Stop";
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            Timer2.Enabled = false;
            Button1.Text = "Start";
        }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   static DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,9,1,0,0,0,000);
   Timer t = new Timer();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false; 
            Timer1.Interval = 1;
            lbl.Text = dt.ToLongTimeString() + ":" + dt.Millisecond;
        }
    }

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(1);
    lbl.Text = dt.ToLongTimeString() + ":" + dt.Millisecond;
}


protected void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false; //For stop the timer
    dt = new DateTime(2014, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 000);
    lbl.Text = dt.ToLongTimeString() + ":" + dt.Millisecond;

}
protected void Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false; //For stop the timer

}
protected void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = true; // For starting the timer
}
```

}